# Python equivalent of `wavedec3` from MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, dwt

I am trying to implement a discrete wavelet transform (DWT) in 3D, and I have found the MATLAB equivalent, `wavedec3`. Does anyone know if there is a Python equivalent I can use rather than going ahead and writing my own?

Comment: This search yields several Python packages for 3D wavelet transform: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+n3d+wavelet+transform

Comment: We also have one in DIPlib: https://diplib.github.io/diplib-docs/group__transform.html#ga96183c6399339ff2fe31b230a64e3a4e — and this propaganda is exactly why this type of question is considered off-topic on Stack Overflow. “How do I compute...” is a better question than “Is there an implementation of ...”

Comment: @CrisLuengo I did not know there is a `wavedecn`, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [pywt](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/nd-dwt-and-idwt.html) the `wavedecn(array, method, level)` and it does what I wanted to do: perform discrete wavelet transform on a 3D array in multi-levels.